# Gulp HTML minify for custom tags not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify

Here is a short version of my HTML page which has `<xmp>` for code snippets tag:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Aqua Dotted Link - Default</a>

  <br /><br />

  <a href="#" class="a-gold">Gold Dotted Link</a>

  <h3>Code for Footer: </h3>
  <pre><code><xmp><u>This is U tag with underlined aqua - Default </u>

  <u class="u-gold">This is U tag with underlined gold</u>

  <u class="u-orange">This is U tag with underlined orange</u></xmp></code></pre>

  <p>Hello World</p>

  <p>Hello World 2</p>
</div>
```

With `gulp-htmlmin` I'm doing the following in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
let htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

...

gulp.task('html', gulp.series('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(globs.html)
   .pipe(htmlmin({
     collapseWhitespace: true,
     removeComments: true,
   }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}));

...
```

I don't know what's wrong, but here's the output I get:

```
<div class=container><a href=#>Aqua Dotted Link - Default</a><br><br><a href=# class=a-gold>Gold Dotted Link</a><h3>Code for Footer:</h3><pre><code><xmp><u>This is U tag with underlined aqua - Default </u>

  <u class=u-gold>This is U tag with underlined gold</u>

  <u class=u-orange>This is U tag with underlined orange</u></xmp></code></pre><p>Hello World<p>Hello World 2</div>
```

How can I make gulp to recognize `<xmp>` tag so that it can minify it?

Answer (score 0):

`<xmp>` is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp).

Try to use `<pre>` or `<code>` instead of `<xmp>`.

Comment: I know it's obsolete, but if I use `<pre><code> <h1>Hello World</h1> </pre></code>` this peice of code, it's actually rendering `Hello World` on my HTML in big heading. So I'm using `<pre><code><xmp><h1>Hello World</h1></xmp></pre></code>` so it now renders `<h1>Hello World</h1>` on my HTML page

Comment: So, is there a way in Gulp to recognize this? How do gulp users minify stuff for say custom tags like `<Render>` or any other custom web component tag?

Comment: Hi. So I figured out regarding your issue with minifying your html code. The code between `<pre>` and `</pre>` won't be minified for obvious reason (to save code formatting, spaces, etc.), and if you remove `<pre>` tag from your markup your code will be minified with custom tags as well.